# Difference between React.FunctionComponent and React.SFC

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What is the difference between React.FunctionComponent and React.SFC. I'm new To typescript, and actually I don't know when to use one over the other. for example when using react hooks should I use only React.FunctionComponent, because I use some sort of state inside my component.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`React.SFC` (which stands for *stateless function component*) is [an alias](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/2fc40ca501f2cc734deb9313fa1032e3381a0e26/types/react/index.d.ts#L458) for `React.FunctionComponent`.

It was deprecated because functional components aren't *stateless* since React 16.8.

Answer (score 10):

They are the same, just one a newer terminology. Have a look at the definitions, they are both aliases for the same definition:

```
type SFC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;
type FC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;
```

Comment: yes that's correct, I looked to the code source and they mentioned that React.SFC is deprecated because of The new React Hooks: ```/**
     * @deprecated as of recent React versions, function components can no
     * longer be considered 'stateless'. Please use `FunctionComponent` instead.
     *
     * @see [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)
     */
    type SFC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;```